# DB2 10.1 FP4 DB2START gives error

Tags: windows, db2

I installed DB2 10.1 FP4 on Windows server 2012 R2 successfully. 
When I try to start database using db2start I am getting below error.

DB2 : The service has returned a service-specific error code.
SQL1042C  An unexpected system error occurred.  SQLSTATE=58004

### db2diag.log has below error.

```
2015-05-14-16.34.51.630000+540 I95881F1126   LEVEL: Error
PID : 4728 TID : 4996 PROC : db2syscs.exe
INSTANCE: DB2 NODE : 000
HOSTNAME: <Machine name>
EDUID   : 4996 EDUNAME: db2sysc
FUNCTION: DB2 Common, Cryptography, cryptDynamicLoadGSKitCrypto, probe:998
MESSAGE : ECF=0x90000076=-1879048074=ECF_LIB_CANNOT_LOAD
   Cannot load the specified library
DATA #1 : unsigned integer, 4 bytes
70
DATA #2 : String, 48 bytes
D:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\bin\icc64\gsk8iccs_64.dll
CALLSTCK: 
  [0] 0x00007FF93D9642A4 pdOSSeLoggingCallback + 0x134
  [1] 0x00007FF93EF1033E ossLog + 0x15E
  [2] 0x00007FF93EF1023B ossLog + 0x5B
  [3] 0x00007FF91D8E75ED cryptDynamicLoadGSKitCrypto + 0x65D
  [4] 0x00007FF91D8E6724 cryptContextRealInit + 0x144
  [5] 0x00007FF91D8E6337 cryptContextInit + 0x117
  [6] 0x00007FF91C9002E5 sqloRunInstance + 0x1C5
  [7] 0x00007FF691442700 0x00007FF691442700 + 0x0
  [8] 0x00007FF691441974 0x00007FF691441974 + 0x0
  [9] 0x00007FF946B516AD BaseThreadInitThunk + 0xD
  [10] 0x00007FF946D04629 RtlUserThreadStart + 0x1D

2015-05-14-16.34.51.834000+540 I97009F922 LEVEL: Error
PID : 4728 TID : 4996 PROC : db2syscs.exe
INSTANCE: DB2 NODE : 000
HOSTNAME: <Machine name>
EDUID   : 4996 EDUNAME: db2sysc
FUNCTION: DB2 Common, Cryptography, cryptContextInit, probe:105
MESSAGE : ECF=0x90000076=-1879048074=ECF_LIB_CANNOT_LOAD
   Cannot load the specified library
DATA #1 : Hex integer, 4 bytes
0x90000076
CALLSTCK: 
  [0] 0x00007FF93D9642A4 pdOSSeLoggingCallback + 0x134
  [1] 0x00007FF93EF1033E ossLog + 0x15E
  [2] 0x00007FF93EF1023B ossLog + 0x5B
  [3] 0x00007FF91D8E63D5 cryptContextInit + 0x1B5
  [4] 0x00007FF91C9002E5 sqloRunInstance + 0x1C5
  [5] 0x00007FF691442700 0x00007FF691442700 + 0x0
  [6] 0x00007FF691441974 0x00007FF691441974 + 0x0
  [7] 0x00007FF946B516AD BaseThreadInitThunk + 0xD
  [8] 0x00007FF946D04629 RtlUserThreadStart + 0x1D

2015-05-14-16.34.51.834000+540 I97933F426 LEVEL: Severe
PID : 4728 TID : 4996 PROC : db2syscs.exe
INSTANCE: DB2 NODE : 000
HOSTNAME: <Machine name>
EDUID   : 4996 EDUNAME: db2sysc
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, oper system services, sqloRunInstance, probe:50
MESSAGE : ECF=0x90000076=-1879048074=ECF_LIB_CANNOT_LOAD
   Cannot load the specified library

2015-05-14-16.34.51.834000+540 I98361F529 LEVEL: Severe
PID : 4728 TID : 4996 PROC : db2syscs.exe
INSTANCE: DB2 NODE : 000
HOSTNAME: <Machine name>
EDUID   : 4996 EDUNAME: db2sysc
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, base sys utilities, DB2main, probe:2263
MESSAGE : SQL1042C  An unexpected system error occurred.
```

---

Any help is appreciate.

Comment: So, does "D:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\bin\icc64\gsk8iccs_64.dll" exist?

Comment: Thanks for reply. 
'icc64' folder itself doenst exists. What should I do now? any suggestion..

Comment: Problem solved yeeeeee happyyyyy!!!!
Ref:<https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014824111>
*This was for other version of windows OS
For 2012 R2 need to copy all files/folders from <C:\Program Files\IBM\gsk8\lib64> to <D:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN\icc64>. IF 'icc64' folder doesnt exist then create it.

Hope this will help someone who have same problem.

This one is bug of setup program and already reported to IBM at <http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IC89975>. Let hope IBM will release fix soon.

Comment: Please post your comment as an answer.